# PHP: regex match phrase not containing specific word

Tags: php, regex

I'm getting tired of looking around for a close enough example, time for some quick help! Here is my code:

```
preg_match_all( '#<li.*?>.*?</li>#s', $card_html, $activity );
```

I want to modify it so that the `<li.*?>` excludes the word `Unplayed`. (The word comes after the `.*?` and before the `>`.

**Edit**:

`Want to catch: http://gamercard.xbox.com/en-US/Stallion83.card`

```
            <li >

                <a href="http://live.xbox.com/en-us/GameCenter/Achievements?title=1464993792&amp;compareTo=Stallion83">
                   <img src="http://tiles.xbox.com/tiles/vD/fP/1Gdsb2JhbA9ECgUPGgIfVl9TL2ljb24vMC84MDAwIAAAAAAAAPvgN6M=.jpg" alt="F.E.A.R. 3" title="F.E.A.R. 3" />
                   <span class="Title">F.E.A.R. 3</span>
                   <span class="LastPlayed">6/24/2011</span>
                   <span class="EarnedGamerscore">415</span>
                   <span class="AvailableGamerscore">1000</span>
                   <span class="EarnedAchievements">23</span>
                   <span class="AvailableAchievements">50</span>
                   <span class="PercentageComplete">46%</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="Complete" >

                <a href="http://live.xbox.com/en-US/GameCenter/Achievements?title=1096157212&amp;compareTo=Im%20RedJ">
                   <img src="http://tiles.xbox.com/tiles/HI/L4/1Gdsb2JhbA9ECgQJGgYfVl4gL2ljb24vMC84MDAwIAAAAAAAAPvXggM=.jpg" alt="Call of Duty: WaW" title="Call of Duty: WaW" />
                   <span class="Title">Call of Duty: WaW</span>
                   <span class="LastPlayed">6/21/2011</span>
                   <span class="EarnedGamerscore">1500</span>
                   <span class="AvailableGamerscore">1500</span>
                   <span class="EarnedAchievements">66</span>
                   <span class="AvailableAchievements">66</span>
                   <span class="PercentageComplete">100%</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

`Dont want: http://gamercard.xbox.com/en-US/test.card`

```
            <li class="Unplayed"></li>

            <li class="Unplayed"></li>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are already doing something wrong if you use regex to parse HTML. What about a proper HTML parser?

Comment: Because I don't need that much overhead for the project I'm doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.  The lookahead makes sure that the rest of the `<li>` tag does not contain Unplayed.

```
preg_match_all( '#<li(?=(.(?!Unplayed))*?>).*?>(.(?!Unplayed))*?</li>#s', $card_html, $activity );
```

Edit: I couldn't tell from your example, but it sounds like unplayed can occur both outside and inside the begin tag for <li>.

Comment: Close. There are 5 results by default. Your attempt removes all but 1 of the contents containing Unplayed.

Comment: Oh.  Great.  So if you post your example html, I'm sure we can get this figured out.

Comment: I've added the link from where I'm pulling the info from.

Comment: @Dark, take a look at the new one.

Comment: Its still returning one empty recent game.

Comment: @Dark, In the links you posted, when I go to them, there is no variation.  I don't see any games.  Can you post the html?

Comment: @Dark, the regex is working in my (.net) test app.  What is the html for the empty recent game?  Any ideas why it is not matching?

Comment: The empty recent game is posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the right tool for this task and you can see many explanations on SO for this. Use DOMDocument like this:

```
function innerHTML($node){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));   
  return $doc->saveHTML();
}
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
// To hold all your liv...
$lis = array();
// Get all li nodes
$liNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("li");
foreach($liNodes as $liNode) {
  // Check the class attr of each li
  $cl = $liNode->getAttribute("class");
  if ($cl != "Unplayed")
       $lis[] = innerHTML($liNode);
}
print_r($lis);
```

#### OUTPUT for above input html:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
                <a href="http://live.xbox.com/en-us/GameCenter/Achievements?title=1464993792&amp;compareTo=Stallion83">
                   <img src="http://tiles.xbox.com/tiles/vD/fP/1Gdsb2JhbA9ECgUPGgIfVl9TL2ljb24vMC84MDAwIAAAAAAAAPvgN6M=.jpg" alt="F.E.A.R. 3" title="F.E.A.R. 3"><span class="Title">F.E.A.R. 3</span>
                   <span class="LastPlayed">6/24/2011</span>
                   <span class="EarnedGamerscore">415</span>
                   <span class="AvailableGamerscore">1000</span>
                   <span class="EarnedAchievements">23</span>
                   <span class="AvailableAchievements">50</span>
                   <span class="PercentageComplete">46%</span>
                </a>            

    [1] => 
                <a href="http://live.xbox.com/en-US/GameCenter/Achievements?title=1096157212&amp;compareTo=Im%20RedJ">
                   <img src="http://tiles.xbox.com/tiles/HI/L4/1Gdsb2JhbA9ECgQJGgYfVl4gL2ljb24vMC84MDAwIAAAAAAAAPvXggM=.jpg" alt="Call of Duty: WaW" title="Call of Duty: WaW"><span class="Title">Call of Duty: WaW</span>
                   <span class="LastPlayed">6/21/2011</span>
                   <span class="EarnedGamerscore">1500</span>
                   <span class="AvailableGamerscore">1500</span>
                   <span class="EarnedAchievements">66</span>
                   <span class="AvailableAchievements">66</span>
                   <span class="PercentageComplete">100%</span>
                </a> 
)
```